# The right way of using Foundation's "row"

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, grid-layout, zurb-foundation-6

I have a bit trouble with using `row`.
I have this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-2 medium-12 small-12 columns">
      <div class="callout">
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-8 medium-12 small-12  columns">
      <div class="callout">
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-2 medium-12 small-12 columns">
      <div class="callout">
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I get every *Lorem ipsum* under each other, not beside. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You forgot to close `<div class="row">`. Re-indent the markup and you will see.

Comment: @JasonK ok, I that's true, I put it there, but the problem is not resolved. The  callouts is under each other, not beside...

Comment: Looks correct in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ba586Lrr/) for a large screen it is `2-8-2` and for all others it is `12-12-12`

Comment: @t.niese, than why I get the callouts under each other in large screen?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might have been using mark-up suitable for either the legacy 'float' or 'flex' grid system whilst Foundation 6's default enabled is 'XY grid'. Thus, the mark-up is different and would cause your columns to stack.

**Float/flex grid mark-up**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-2 medium-12 small-12 columns">
    <div class="callout">
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-8 medium-12 small-12  columns">
    <div class="callout">
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-2 medium-12 small-12 columns">
    <div class="callout">
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can continue to to use 'float' or 'flex' grids but need to specify which you're using in the project. Or, if you want to use the newer 'XY grid', you can modify your mark-up like so.

**XY grid mark-up**

```
<div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
  <div class="cell large-2 medium-12 small-12">
    <div class="callout">
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell large-8 medium-12 small-12">
    <div class="callout">
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell large-2 medium-12 small-12">
    <div class="callout">
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```